# TypeError: Cannot read property 'providers' of undefined: Truffle & Web3

Tags: web3js, testing, web3-providers

Here is the necessary part of the code, from where I keep receiving the following error:

```
const { Web3 } = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
```

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'providers' of undefined`
Although, the node packages for Web3 are installed. How can I solve this problem?. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth.html#id1) removing the `{}` around `Web3` in the first line should do the trick

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **ethers.js**:

*Don't do*

```js
import ethers from "ethers" // bad
```

*Instead **do***

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers" // good
```